# Are there any other libraries for Image Processing using hadoop?

Tags: image-processing

I have been looking for libraries for Image Processing using hadoop, but by now, only have been able to know about hipi, and to some extent hadoopy. Are there any other libraries for the same?
Hipi uses java programming, so I am looking for some sort of python-integrated programming with Hadoop? Kindly help!